# « C’est à ceux… » ou « C’est ceux… »

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, constructions, formulation, reformulation

C’est à ceux (agents d’intervention) qui prennent le relais de se charger de son cas (usager en crise), pas à toi.

C’est ceux (agents d’intervention) qui prennent le relais qui doivent se charger de son cas (usager en crise), pas toi.

Quelle est la nuance entre les deux formulations? Y en a-t-il une plus correcte que l’autre?

C’est à qui de vs c’est qui qui doit.

Comment: Salut !
Alors je suis parle le français d'un français de France, et dans mon cas, les deux sont correctes. Il n'y a pas de nuances, ça veut exactement dire la même chose, avec des mots différents.

Comment: J'aurais tendance à dire qu'en théorie on devrait dire "Ce sont ceux qui" (même si "C'est ceux" est largement accepté, peu le remarqueraient) et "C'est à ceux". le "c'est à" appuie peut-être plus sur la tâche en question que l'autre, appuyant plus que ce n'est pas à "toi" de le faire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les deux tournures ont exactement le même sens et peuvent être utilisées de manière interchangeable.

> Ce sont eux qui doivent xxx

> C'est à eux de xxx

Je propose les nuances suivantes mais c'est une interprétation subjective, ça dépend du contexte, de l'intonation, etc.

- `c'est à x de` : on utilise cette tournure quand il y a une alternance de tours ("*c'est à elle de jouer*") ou répartition de rôles ("*c'est au gardien d'arrêter la balle*").
  Selon le contexte, cela pourrait signifier implicitement : "si vous le faites, vous outrepassez votre rôle."
- `c'est x qui doit` : le verbe devoir a un sens fort, on insiste sur l'obligation.
  Selon le contexte, cela pourrait signifier implicitement : "s'ils ne le font pas, c'est qu'ils ne font pas leur travail."

Note : on accorde normalement la [locution présentative](https://leflepourlescurieux.fr/c-est-et-ce-sont-les-presentatifs-grammaire-a2/) *c'est* au sujet *réel*, en l'occurrence les agents d'intervention donc pluriel : `ce sont eux qui xxx`.